# How to transform a void * to a member of NSObject

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here is my code,when I want to transform the void * to LuSocket, it crash and say message sent to deallocated instance 0x16662aa0.I don't know why.

```
  static void ReadStreamCallBack(CFReadStreamRef stream, CFStreamEventType  event, void *myPtr){
  if (event == kCFStreamEventOpenCompleted) 
  {
      NSLog(@"ReadStreamEventOpenCompleted");
  }
  else if (event == kCFStreamEventHasBytesAvailable)
  {
      NSLog(@"ReadStreamEventHasBytesAvailable");
      UInt8 buffer[255];
      CFReadStreamRead(stream, buffer, 255);
      printf("read:%s\n",buffer);
      NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",buffer];
      @autoreleasepool {
          LuSocket *temp = (__bridge LuSocket *)myPtr;
      }
  } }
```

Comment: Are you using ARC? Most probably, you didn't take ownership of the object properly and it has been deallocated automatically.

Comment: Is it possible to have the piece of code where you call this function?